# Angular Material 2 DatePicker with only month and year

Tags: angular, typescript, datepicker, angular-material2

I was looking for a way to make the angular material datepicker 2 change to only year and month mode but it does not have that option in the documentation

I can set the startView but when month or year is selected, change to Day mode

```
<md-form-field>
     <input mdInput [mdDatepicker]="picker" placeholder="Choose a date">
     <md-datepicker-toggle mdSuffix [for]="picker"></md-datepicker-toggle>
     <md-datepicker #picker startView="year" [startAt]="startDate"></md-datepicker>
</md-form-field>
```

I want this: https://plnkr.co/edit/eV2Kmt?p=preview

But that plunker is in angular material 1

Any help? :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For this time this is an open bug. [See this link](https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/4853)

Comment: Looks like there's a new PR which appears to have support for year selection, although it also appears that it won't be released until possibly 5.1 (as indicated by the milestone): https://github.com/angular/material2/pull/8565

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there's soon gonna be year support soon, once [this PR](https://github.com/angular/material2/pull/8565) is merged!

(However, it appears that it probably will appear in release 5.1 since it was placed in milestone `5.1`)

Answer (score 0):

In HTML

```
<mat-datepicker #searchDate startView="year" (monthSelected)="monthSelectedHandler($event)"></mat-datepicker>
```

In your controller

```
searchDateValue: FormControl;

ngOnInit() {
    this.searchDateValue = new FormControl(this.searchDate);
}

monthSelectedHandler(event) {
    const date = new Date(`${event._i.month + 1}/${event._i.date}/${event._i.year}`);
    this.searchDateValue.setValue(date);
    this.searchDatePicker.close();
}
```

Comment: This works but not at 100%, you can still access to the day by clicking in the top left field.